# Can Jam be reheated?

Tags: oven, jam, puff-pastry

I just got a bottle of strawberry jam. I am trying to make puff pastry filled with Jam and cream cheese inside it.

I have never done this before. It is just an Idea in my mind so far. I need advice to know that can I heat the Jam in oven. The jam jar says to store in fridge after opening but nothing about it being heated. Can anyone explain whether it's safe to do so or not.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding what you are asking. Are you looking for ways to "melt" the jam?

Comment: sorry i could not explain very well, English is not my first language. But ill try again. I know that jams are made by heating fruit n sugar together, and allowed to cool down. but after its set can i use that set jam inside a puff pastry and let it heat in oven.  will it be safe to consume and stay the same texture. i got this doubt as it said refrigerate after opening on the jar. So i thought once its been set the jam cannot be heated , only cooled

Comment: "Safe" when used about food means "is there a risk that I get sick if I do it" - is this what you were wondering about? If yes, then the texture thing has to be mentioned separately.

Comment: Yes… Example: Spoonful of orange [marmalade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmalade) in warm pan + Splash of [Cointreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointreau) (away from stove) = instant crêpe sauce

Comment: If you need the jam runny or runnier before use, it is quite OK to pop it in the microwave (without the lid of course) for a short time.

Comment: Great tips.. I tried my puff pastry with Jam filling... It turned out better than I thought it would.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure it's safe, there's no risk in putting jam in baked goods. It says refrigerate after opening so it doesn't spoil after being left out too long - some people don't realize it needs to be refrigerated after opening because it is stored in the cupboard before opening.

The important thing for food safety is to make sure that the pastries are eaten soon enough after baking. The cream cheese will go off sooner than the jam will, so don't let them sit around.

Answer (score 7):

Yep. No problem at all. This is standard practise for using up left over pastry: jam tarts.

Just be careful to let the jam cool down before you bite into it. You don't want molten jam all over the roof of your mouth.

Comment: The concept of "left over pastry" does not parse..

Comment: @keshlam think of left-over-dough pastries

Answer (score 4):

Should be safe to heat your jam. I have reheated jams over the stove but never in the oven and have not encountered any problems with it.

It is always safe to reheat your jam. Reasons for reheating jams may vary, but be warned: "they may or may not form a gel again once they are re-heated, as over-cooking of pectin can reduce or destroy its ability to form the gel structure." [-National Center for Home Food Preservation.](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_07/stiff_jelly.html)

Comment: That's really good information. It really helped. Made my life easy.

Answer (score 3):

A traditionally made jam is actually a preserve that has, by the copious amounts of sugar involved and often by natural acidity, some added resilience against spoilage compared to a random ingredient - the practically most encountered spoilage mode for jams is mold. A "diet" style jam that uses artificial sweeteners and no or little sugar could conceivably spoil in different ways *if* left in conditions outside of the usual 2 hour/4 hour/danger zone envelope (not an issue in reheating, can become an issue if reheated goods are kept on the table for hours).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, but make sure to eat the pastry before the cream cheese spoils.

Comment: Welcome Aysha - Short answers don't do well here. Longer answers with explanations are prefered.  If you haven't already done so, you might want to take the tour and see haw this site works. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour